# In ruby which is better, detect or index, to find an object in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of objects.
I want to find an object in the array based on some property of the object.

I can do

```
array.detect {|x| x.name=="some name"}
```

or I could do

```
ind=array.index {|x| x.name=="some name"}
array[ind] unless ind.nil?
```

Is there any reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking? `detect` obviously fits better for what you want to do.

Comment: If you want to find the object, I'd do the `detect`...  Like your code example above, you're parsing the array **then** doing the lookup if you use `index`.

Comment: I tried benchmarking and detect worked better. Used an array of 10k objects. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Something to consider: If your array is going to be large, then look at using a hash, where the object property you want to find is the key and the value is the actual object. A hash is a random-access container, and it retrieving objects from it will outrun using `detect` or `index`, especially as the container gets bigger. There are other options too which will outrun `detect`, like using a tree, or a sorted array with a binary search. In other words, don't just throw stuff in an array and hope some method for retrieving the data will be fast.

Comment: Makes much more sense to use a hash. Will do that instead of using detect, index.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't interested in finding the index value of the object you're searching for, I would suggest `detect`. It'll save you from having to do that `nil` check before accessing the array.

From a performance standpoint, I imagine it's relatively comparable, but that could help your decision too. That would require benchmarking as Niels B. mentioned in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find an element in a collection, it's important to use collections made for fast retrieval. Arrays are not made for that, nor are they particularly convenient unless you are making a stack or a queue.

Here's some code to show ways to improve the storage/retrieval speed over what you can get using `find`, `detect` or other normal array-based methods:

```
require 'fruity'
require 'digest'

class Foo

  attr_reader :var1, :var2

  def initialize(var1, var2)
    @var1, @var2 = var1, var2
  end

end

START_INT  = 1
START_CHAR = 'a'
END_INT    = 10
END_CHAR   = 'z'

START_MD5 = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(START_INT.to_s + START_CHAR)
END_MD5   = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(END_INT.to_s   + END_CHAR)

ary = []
hsh = {}
hsh2 = {}

START_INT.upto(END_INT) do |i|
  (START_CHAR .. END_CHAR).each do |j|
    foo = Foo.new(i, j)

    ary << foo
    hsh[[i, j]] = foo
    hsh2[Digest::MD5.hexdigest(i.to_s + j)] = foo
  end
end

compare do

  array_find {
    ary.find { |a| (a.var1 == START_INT) && (a.var2 == START_CHAR) }
    ary.find { |a| (a.var1 == END_INT)   && (a.var2 == END_CHAR)   }
  }

  hash_access_with_array {
    hsh[[START_INT, START_CHAR]]
    hsh[[END_INT, END_CHAR]]
  }

  hash_access_with_digest {
    hsh2[START_MD5]
    hsh2[END_MD5]
  }

end
```

Which results in:

```
Running each test 16384 times. Test will take about 17 seconds.
hash_access_with_digest is faster than hash_access_with_array by 10x ± 1.0
hash_access_with_array is faster than array_find by 16x ± 1.0
```

There are three different tests, and I'm looking for the first, and last elements in the array `ary`, and the corresponding objects in the hashes. The result of looking for the first and last elements in the array will be an average time for that search. For comparison I'm searching for the same objects in the hashes.

If we had some advance knowledge of which array index the object is in, retrieving the object from the array would be faster, but that's the problem, and making another container to keep track of that information would be slower than using the hash.

Answer (score 0):

See for yourself!

```
require 'benchmark'

array = (1..1000000).to_a

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report("#index for 1") {
    array.index(1)
  }

  x.report("#detect 1") {
    array.detect { |i| i == 1 }
  }

  x.report("#index for 500k") {
    array.index(500000)
  }

  x.report("#detect 500k") {
    array.detect { |i| i == 500000 }
  }

  x.report("#index for 1m") {
    array.index(1000000)
  }

  x.report("#detect 1m") {
    array.detect { |i| i == 1000000 }
  }
end
```

Put the code above in a file and execute it from the console with `ruby <file>`

Ignore the top block, that is rehearsal, the bottom block should look something like this:

```
                      user     system      total        real
#index for 1      0.000005   0.000002   0.000007 (  0.000004)
#detect 1         0.000007   0.000002   0.000009 (  0.000006)
#index for 500k   0.003274   0.000049   0.003323 (  0.003388)
#detect 500k      0.029870   0.000200   0.030070 (  0.030872)
#index for 1m     0.005866   0.000009   0.005875 (  0.005880)
#detect 1m        0.059819   0.000520   0.060339 (  0.061340)
```

Running on my mac and Ruby 2.5.0, the numbers seem to suggest that `#detect` is an order of magnitude slower than `#index`.